# Consume offset Diff is negative, what are the possible casue?

Tags: rocketmq

Sometimes, it will occure that the diff of consume offset and broker offset is negative which is quite abnormal.

There are many users of the community who meet this problem.

This question is to list all possible causes and the the solution.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is a known concurrent bug which has been fix in release 3.4.6(See the release note here: https://github.com/alibaba/RocketMQ/releases)

BTW, you are highly recommended to use the latest release of the Apache RocketMQ(https://github.com/apache/incubator-rocketmq/), we always have compatibility in mind. Further, using latest release, you may expect significant performance enhancement, new features, bug fixes.